# Grouping up adjacent elements together in python

Tags: python, list, grouping

Given a list like this, where first column is the id and second is a string,

```
[ [2, ["00_01_02"]],
  [1, ["00_03_04"]],
  [3, ["00_03_04"]],
  [6, ["00_03_04"]],
  [4, ["01_02_03"]],
  [5, ["01_02_03"]],    
 ]
```

As you can see there are adjacent elements that are the same. For example, the id 1,3 and 6 have the same string so I would like to group them up into another list. Same goes for id 5 and 4. We can also assume that the list is in sorted order by the string.

I would like to solve this problem in 
O(NC) if possible, where N is the number of element in the list, C is the number of characters in the string.

Example output would be something like,

```
[ [[1,3,6], ["00_03_04"]],
  [[4,5]  , ["01_02_03"]] ]
```

Comment: You might want to look into using a dictionary

Comment: I did actually check it out and I have a solution using a dictionary. But the thing is that my solution doesn't take into account the fact that items are adjacent to each other. I'll post my solution below.

Comment: Where did `2, ["00_01_02"]` went in your output, shopping?

Comment: @Rahul i am only looking for strings with 2 or more similar ids

Comment: Fair Enought. Did any of the answer worked for you?

Comment: The problem is not adequately specified. **What should happen** if some entries with matching strings are **not** adjacent? Should they be merged, or form separate groups? There are separate approaches to each problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools` for efficiency -

```
a = [ [2, ["00_01_02"]],
  [1, ["00_03_04"]],
  [3, ["00_03_04"]],
  [6, ["00_03_04"]],
  [4, ["01_02_03"]],
  [5, ["01_02_03"]],    
  [7, ["00_03_04"]],
 ]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

print([ [[ g[0] for g in grp], key] for key, grp in groupby(a, key=itemgetter(1))])
```

**Output**

```
[[[2], ['00_01_02']], [[1, 3, 6], ['00_03_04']], [[4, 5], ['01_02_03']], [[7], ['00_03_04']]]
```

Comment: is there a way to group them together while taking into account that the second column is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use [collectins.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [ [2, ["00_01_02"]],
  [1, ["00_03_04"]],
  [3, ["00_03_04"]],
  [6, ["00_03_04"]],
  [4, ["01_02_03"]],
  [5, ["01_02_03"]],    
 ]

for v, k in l:
    new_d[k[0]].append(v)


new_d
Out[102]: defaultdict(list, {'00_01_02': [2], '00_03_04': [1, 3, 6], '01_02_03': [4, 5]})
```

If you want the similar output as you requested.

```
[[v,[k]] for k,v in new_d.items() if len(v) > 1]
Out[118]: [[[1, 3, 6], ['00_03_04']], [[4, 5], ['01_02_03']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in one line:

```
data=[ [2, ["00_01_02"]],
  [1, ["00_03_04"]],
  [3, ["00_03_04"]],
  [6, ["00_03_04"]],
  [4, ["01_02_03"]],
  [5, ["01_02_03"]],
 ]

import itertools

print([list(j) for i,j in itertools.groupby(data,key=lambda x:x[1][0])])
```

output:

```
[[[2, ['00_01_02']]], [[1, ['00_03_04']], [3, ['00_03_04']], [6, ['00_03_04']]], [[4, ['01_02_03']], [5, ['01_02_03']]]]
```

if you don't want to use any import then:

```
similar={}
for j in data:
    if j[1][0] not in similar:
        similar[j[1][0]]=[j[0]]
    else:
        similar[j[1][0]].append(j[0])
print(similar)
```

output:

```
{'01_02_03': [4, 5], '00_01_02': [2], '00_03_04': [1, 3, 6]}
```